# Replacing null values does not work in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have some columns that are empty in my dataset.

```
C1;C2
 ;;;
 ;;;
 ;;;
 ;;;
```

I did simple operation that replace empty values by specific space length if it is only empty.

Because C1 and C2 have sometimes respectivly these values :

```
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

So that I want to replace them by same string length using space string

So I tried like this

```
(C1 =='' ? CONCAT(C1,'               '): C1) AS     C1,
(C2 =='' ? CONCAT(C2,'             '):C2) AS    C2;
```

But this doesn't resolve the problem.
Any help, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
((C1 is null) OR (C1 == '')) ? ...
```